# Humorous author pictures

Tags: publications

Some journals put author pictures and short bios at the end of the articles. Do you know of published examples in which the authors used humorous pictures of themselves, for instance with funny poses or unusual hats?

Comment: Next paper I'll have to try with my profile picture ;-)

Comment: What's funny about hats? ;-) (Disclaimer: In my photo I have a hat.)

Comment: @StuartGolodetz We should introduce parentheses in the English language to disambiguate between *funny (poses or hats)*, and *(funny poses) or hats*. ;-)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni You can use an Oxford comma in these cases. So, _funny poses, or hats_ is very different from _funny poses or hats_.

Comment: And, technically, I am also curious to see if someone managed to get a picture with a [colander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Spaghetti_Monster#Headgear_in_identity_photos) published. It is a complicated subject to argue whether this should be considered a laughing matter or not.

Comment: In geosciences (particularly field geology or sedimentology) the practice of taking pictures of an outcrop or a fossil with someone standing next to it for scale is quite widespread and it is not uncommon for authors to use such pictures to illustrate their bios (I can't seem to find an example right now however because to be honest fewer and fewer journals have short bios at the end of the article in this field; so this observation is at this point just based on vague memories).

Comment: Do the Nobel prize pictures count? https://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2016/kosterlitz_postcard.jpg

Comment: [Some people](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Feynman) like doing that in *books* they publish, if that counts.

Comment: @101010111100: That wouldn’t be an Oxford comma.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano (not a picture but) [Lev Landau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Landau) joked about his name deriving from the French "L'âne Dau" Dau, the donkey. (according to [Lifshitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evgeny_Lifshitz) in the introduction to their "[Mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Course_of_Theoretical_Physics)" book)

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires He he, true! I read that book some 25 years ago and I didn't recall the story. I suspect, though, to be much more "donkey" than Landau ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, a group of authors (Đurić, Delibašić, Radišić, or Đu**i**rić, Deli**l**bašić and Radisic, as they signed themselves in the paper) trying to debunk the Metalurgia International journal provided outrageous pictures in their paper entitled: Evaluation of Transformative Hermeneutic Heuristics for Processing Random Data.

The, up to that point "respected", journal published the paper without any comments about the photos.

Comment: Could you post a link to either the article or the photo used?

Comment: Note for whoever does not get it: They look like the Marx Brothers

Comment: Link to the paper: https://www.scribd.com/doc/167706815/EVALUATION-OF-TRANSFORMATIVE-HERMENEUTIC-HEURISTICS-FOR-PROCESSING-RANDOM-DATA

Comment: I didn't get the Marks Brothers link, and wondered why they were "outrageous." It would be good to edit this in to the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Richard Baraniuk at Rice University has co-authored several papers that I've come across in my research that qualify, to some degree:

1. J. Laska and R. Baraniuk, [“Regime change: Bit-depth versus measurement-
   rate in compressive sensing,”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2012.2194710) *IEEE Trans. Signal Process.*, vol. 60, no. 7, pp. 3496–3505, 2012.

The author photos in this paper seem to be a play on "regime change" mentioned in the title: one author's photo appears to be that of a political candidate after hearing that they've lost an election, while the other author photo is presumably of the "victorious" candidate.

2. M. Davenport, J. Laska, J. Treichler, and R. Baraniuk, [“The pros and
   cons of compressive sensing for wideband signal acquisition: Noise
   folding versus dynamic range,”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2012.2201149) *IEEE Trans. Signal Process.*, vol. 60,
   no. 9, pp. 4628–4642, Sep. 2012.

There are four author photos: two authors have "sad" faces, two "happy."

3. M. A. Davenport, R. G. Baraniuk, and C. D. Scott, [“Tuning support
   vector machines for minimax and Neyman-Pearson classification,”](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2010.29) *IEEE Trans. Pattern Anal. Mach. Intell.*, vol. 32, no. 10, pp. 1888–1898, Oct. 2010.

In this paper two of the authors have the word "minimax" (from the paper title) in the background of their photos, which appear to be on signs of some sort (the third author has a street sign in the photo background; what it says, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 5):

So far, I haven't come across any pictures in the short bio section which I could call 'funny'. However, I have seen quite an odd picture of a co-author which seems like a infrared imaging of the author.

That paper is quite popular in its field. It is called *"The HumanID Gait Challenge Problem: Data Sets, Performance, and Analysis."* It contained a photo of Prof. Kevin W. Bowyer; [this was his short bio picture](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/mediastore/IEEE/content/freeimages/34/30027/1374864/1374864-photo-6-small.gif) in the paper. I'll also like to add that this paper is published in the IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis.

Comment: The cited photo is not a negative (try inverting its colors); it's an image from a thermal imaging camera. Note the poor resolution, along with the scattered bad pixels; that's due to the (as yet) high cost of the PIR sensors used.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Thanks for pointing it out. I've made the edit.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at Poizat's "Groupes stable", although a reviewer of the English translation wrote

> As the author is no doubt aware, his tasteless joke
>   in the  French edition  of this  book  crossed the  line  between  offensive  and insulting.

Comment: ... but crossed it in which direction?

Comment: Is a picture available on the internet?

Comment: Poizat was told that writing in French was bad for sales, so as a parody to market adaptation he included pictures which he described as "gentilement porno".